# Ionic - Build for IOS on Windows (for latest IOS and Ionic)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I successfully built my app for Android, but naturally things are not that simple for IOS for a windows user.

This question has been asked many times before in many places at different times in different versions, but I'm interested to see if there's any up-to-date info on the issue.

Here's an old topic with a variety of answers: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-app-for-iphone-without-mac/19929/19

I'm using ionic 3 and I'd like to build for the latest IOS, My PC OS is Windows 10.
Does Ionic provide any way to make this process easier?

I understood that in the latest IOS an apple dev account is no longer a requirement for testing. How do I test without one? (perhaps it's possible only when using a MAC?)

How do I use PhoneGap Build with Ionic?
https://build.phonegap.com/apps

It requires apple app certificate and keys to build.

Am I supposed to manually create a config.xml? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world/blob/master/www/config.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research I found out that ionic has a cloud packaging service.
https://ionicframework.com/pro/package (previously https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/ [link dead])

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: It's now called AppFlow: https://ionic.io/appflow

Answer (score 9):

I use windows to develop Ionic. In order to build for IOS I have installed VMWare on which I emulate MacOS X, installed xcode and all the tools necessary for building ionic. I have been able to test and deploy my apps to an ios device through usb with ionic/xcode. However I haven't push any apps to the app store yet. If you want to get started into this, take a look at this [link](http://www.iblogapple.com/2017/03/10/install-macos-sierra-on-windows-using-vmware-virtual-machine/).

Comment: Yup that's the good old answer, but I was hoping that more options appeared over time.

Comment: Link mentioned in the answer is either dead or moved. Here is the new link: http://www.iblogapple.com/2017/03/13/install-macos-sierra-on-windows-using-vmware-virtual-machine/

Comment: Where can I get MacOS iso ?